# Events in custom calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, custom-controls

I created a `Calender` named `CALENDAR1` and dynamically created a `LinkButton` named as `Login` in every cell(created in the `DayRender` event). I need to perform `Click` event when I click the `Login`. Is there any options to do this?

```
 protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

    LinkBut.Text = "<br>Login";

    DateTime time = e.Day.Date;
    string form="dd";
    string day = time.ToString(form);
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(day);

    if(e.Day.Date<=System.DateTime.Today)
    {
        Timein.Text= Convert.ToString(i)+"<br>";
        e.Cell.Controls.AddAt(0,Timein);
    }

    if (e.Day.IsToday)
    {

        e.Cell.Controls.AddAt(2, LinkBut);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show what you've tried and how you've created the `HyperLinks`. However, if you want a postback and a `Click`-event you should use a `LinkButton` instead. Then just add the event-handler where you can cast the `sender` argument to `LinkButton`:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
    btn.Click += LinkClicked;
    e.Cell.Controls.Add(btn);
}

private void LinkClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LinkButton btn = (LinkButton) sender;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the Inconvenience Tim. Unfortunately I cant add Images to my Questions. Since I doesn't have enough reputation. Also 1 more problem the LinkButton in my Calendar doesn't seems to be LinkButton. Its just like Label....

Comment: You could add the link to the image to your question and we'll edit your question accordingly. However, the problem is not clear and you've mentioned that you've created `HyperLinks` instead of `Labels`.

Comment: @Elango_Thanumalayan: You should also include the code where you create these controls. And you haven't mentioned the problem with my code.